# Nodejs - why does the response from node coming as a whole?

Tags: node.js

While trying to follow some tutorials on node I found that 
If I have two

response.write()

one in

createServer()

method and another in

setTimeout()

function in createServer then I see -
The response comes as soon as it is written if I make request using 
curl on ubuntu 
and another comes after timeout as expected
But if I open in chrome it loads the page only after timeout and I don't see any different chunks in network debugger of chrome. But only one response which is in contrast to the curl usage, 
Can anyone tell me if I am making this mistake or browsers are implemented this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a browser's behavior. Browser should render whole page at once to ensure page's continuity.